# Angular 2 - Delete Request with parameters

Tags: angular, parameters, http-delete

I need to do a delete request that takes 2 parameters, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

my code looks like this:

```
public deleteDefinition(typeName: string, id: number) {
    console.log("in API call");
    const path = `${this.apiEndpoint}/Definition/Delete/`;
    return this.http.delete(path, typeName, id)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

But I keep receiving the errror

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

What is wrong with my syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The signature is `http.delete(url, options)`. You should include the `id` in the url. As for your `typeName` param, I don't know what it means.

Comment: @AngularFrance okay so I changed my variable path to include the params, and now I do a  `return this.http.delete(path)` however, nothing happens. in my console I can't even see the request, so is it not doing the call at all?

Comment: Observables are executed **only when they are subscribed**. Can you confirm that somewhere in your code you have something like `XXX.deleteDefinition(a, b).subscribe()`?

Comment: @AngularFrance that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

passing a body message to an HTTP DELETE action is not currently supported in Angular 2. HTTP DELETE calls are also not meant to be send with extra info in the body.

One solution would be to change the URL structure so you don't have to provide information in the body.

Another solution is to use POST instead of DELETE. POST does allow you to provide a message body.